# Vite build warns: script can't be bundled without type="module" attribute

Tags: javascript, vite

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./scripts/auth.js"></script>
```

```
# Vite terminal after running "npm run build"
build started...
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@rc/dist/js.cookie.min.js">
in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
```

I'm trying to add some external scripts to my `index.html` but the Vite build process assumes I want to have these scripts bundled. Is there any way to suppress this message?

Answer (score 5):

There is an easy answer, and it is actually in the log itself.

Just add the `type="module"` attribute to your script tags.

like so:
`<script type="module" src="/src/main.js"></script>`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is incorrect advice. If you actually try to execute a script as a module, in general it won't reliably work. For example, modules are automatically executed in javascript strict mode, while traditional scripts are not. That is enough to crash many scripts.

Answer (score 1):

I think I figured it out, but as always ymmv.

You might be able to do this in main.js or app.vue if you need it global, but I only needed the external script on one page. The old-school approach seemed to do it:

```
    mounted() {
      let externalScript = document.createElement('script');
      externalScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://[scripturletc].min.js')
      document.head.appendChild(externalScript)
    }
```

note: if you're doing your components in the new vue3 way, I think the above lines would go in your setup block.

Comment: Loading the script manually like this should technically get around the warning but that seems pretty cumbersome and I wonder if Vite has another suggested way. TY anyway.

Comment: yah, it's totally a workaround, but I haven't found a sleeker vite-approved way yet. if you do, lmk!

Comment: Just keep the warning :) 
There is work on the way:
https://github.com/vitejs/vite/pull/11138